# How to sort, and then pick one item

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I'm using XSLT to get data out of a feed. Currently I use this [block of code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which simply picks the first item out of the feed. I changed it a bit so it applies to this sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="catalog/book/author"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to sort the xml by price, and *then* pick the author associated with the highest priced book. I've tried all kind of things, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The current output is "Gambardella, Matthew", but I need it to be "Galos, Mike".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify an `<xsl:sort>` inside apply-templates, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/book">
                <xsl:sort select="price" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

and then in your little 'book' template, use the `position()` to filter out only the first book node

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. My second question was how to filter the second item from the sorted list, but it's answered as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I want to sort the xml by price, and then pick the author associated with the highest priced book.

FWIW, you can do that with pure XPath, too.

```
/catalog/book[not(price < /catalog/book/price)]/author
```

*(The predicate reads: "Select any `<book>` whose `<price>` is not lower than that of any book.")*

This would select `<author>Galos, Mike</author>` in the [sample XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Notes

- This expression does not select **the** highest priced book, but **all** highest-priced books (i.e., it would select two books if there were two with the same price). Use

  ```
  /catalog/book[not(price < /catalog/book/price)][1]/author
  ```

  to select exactly one matching book (the first one in document order would be selected).
- XPath automatically coerces both operands of a *"less/greater than (or equal to)"*-type of comparison to [numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Number). As long as the values of `<price>` are directly convertible to numbers, the above expression will succeed.
- It must be the inverse logic (*"not(lower than any)"*), because the opposite (*"greater than any"*) can never be true (whereas *"greater than or equal to any"* would always be true).
- The time complexity of a `nodeset1[expression < nodeset2]` operations is:
  → *O(count(nodeset1) × count(nodeset2))*.
  In the above case `nodeset1` and `nodeset2`are identical, so the effective time complexity is:
  → *O(n²)*.
  In other words, it is not the most efficient way to solve this problem (I would say that `<xsl:apply-templates>` with `<xsl:sort>` is), but on the other hand - it's a one-liner that might very well be fast enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need  and to use the position function to only return only the first one:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/book">
                <xsl:sort select="price" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:if test="position()=first()">
       <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `position()=first()` is equivalent to `position()=1`, only longer.